# TortoiseSVN: add change to previous revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've been wondering about this quite a while and so far haven't found any information about it but I am pretty sure this must be possible.

Sometimes when I check in with TortoiseSVN I notice afterwards that there is still anothing change that should have been committed with the check-in. For instance a file that wasn't added although it belonged to the changes or maybe a minor error that has been overlooked. What I'd like to do then is to commit that pending change to the already committed revision. That way each revision contains all related changes.

So my question is: does anybody if there's an easy way to do this?

Comment: Take more time when you do a commit to review the changes you are making and make sure it is everything you expect. This is something that should be done regardless of which version control system you are using.

Comment: I agree crashmstr, but still mistakes can be made. Besides it aren't only mistakes. An additional minor bug can also be fixed just afterwards, that wasn't noticed before. Although I understand many developers don't mind an additional commit, I do like to keep my commits 'atomic'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is there not an easy way to do this, there is *no way* to do this, unless you have access to administer the repository, and unless you don't mind potentially breaking other people's working copies (if they've already updated to the incomplete revision). You would need to strip out the incomplete version from the repository via a dump and reload, and then re-commit all the changes including the extra file.

Just commit an "oops" revision. If it's enabled on your server, you could also consider updating the commit message of the incomplete commit to alert people there is another change that wasn't included.

Comment: Good point. Yeah I guess with already updated working copies that won't be possible indeed. Thanks. Updating the comment is the best option then I think.